# WPF DisplayMemberProperty not functioning as expected in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, bind

I have a simple `ObservableCollection` of a Person class that I am trying to bind in code. Everything binds fine except the `DisplayMemberProperty` which when an item in the dropdown is selected just show a Null in the text part of the dropdown. If I add `DD.DisplayMember = "Lastname"` it works fine but as I need to add the controls at runtime and not all will be dropdowns I need to get this to work as a binding.

My XAML:

```
<Syncfusion:SfMultiColumnDropDownControl x:Name="DD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Margin="20"/>
```

My Code:

```
With OC
    .Add(New Person With {.Id = "1", .Lastname = "Smith"})
    .Add(New Person With {.Id = "2", .Lastname = "Jones"})
    .Add(New Person With {.Id = "3", .Lastname = "Johnson"})
End With

Dim ItemsSourceBinding As New Binding
With ItemsSourceBinding
    .Source = OC
    .Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
    .UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
End With
BindingOperations.SetBinding(DD, SfMultiColumnDropDownControl.ItemsSourceProperty, ItemsSourceBinding)

Dim SelectedItemBinding As New Binding
With SelectedItemBinding
    .Source = Report
    .Path = New PropertyPath("MyPerson")
    .Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
    .UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged 
End With
BindingOperations.SetBinding(DD, SfMultiColumnDropDownControl.SelectedItemProperty, SelectedItemBinding)

Dim DisplayMemberBinding As New Binding
With DisplayMemberBinding
    .Source = OC
    .Path = New PropertyPath("Lastname")
    .Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
    .UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
End With
BindingOperations.SetBinding(DD, SfMultiColumnDropDownControl.DisplayMemberProperty, DisplayMemberBinding)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DisplayMemberProperty` is not supposed to be bound. It is supposed to be set to the name, i.e. a `string`, of a property:

```
DD.DisplayMemberProperty = "LastName"
```

If you bind it to a source property, you need to make sure that this property returns the `string` "Lastname" and not the *value* of the `Lastname` property.